# I see a requests.exceptions.SSLError when working API calling from a site

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

My code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json'
r = requests.get(url)
print('Status code:', r.status_code)
```

and error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hacker-news.firebaseio.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v0/topstories.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1125)')))
```

What's the problem?

Comment: wrong version of protocol...

Answer (score 1):

There might be a larger network problem at play here causing this ssql error but to remedy this quicker do the following:

```
requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

You are bypassing the SSL for now.